¿Por que mi componente no puede generar rutas dinamicas?
Estoy tratando de generar en mi componente una ruta dinamica:
import { FC } from "react";
import { NameCountry } from "@/interface/CountryFull";


const dinamycRequest = async (name:string) =>{
  const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/data.json/view/${name}`);
  const response = await data.json();

  return response;
}

const page:FC<NameCountry> = ({params}) =>{
  const renderRequest = dinamycRequest(params.name)
  console.log(params)
  return(<>
    <h1>Nombre de pais: {params.name}</h1>
    <hr/>
    <h4>{JSON.stringify(renderRequest)}</h4>
  </>)
}

export default page

El problema esta en que cuando quiero stringificar y renderizar la informacion de prueba no me muestra nada, me muestra solo unas llaves vacias, lo que da fe de que la funcion 'dinamycRequest' no me esta devolviendo nada.

Yo creo que el problema radica en que el data.json no esta alojado en un servidor sino en mi carpeta public, creo que no puedo hacer lo mismo que venia haciendo desde apis alojadas en servidores donde ya habian rutas, y esto tiene sentido ya que si probaba el json con la direccion: 'http://localhost:3000/data.json/' este me mostraba el json

Pero si ponia la direccion de la ruta dinamica, la cual se supone deberia funcionar, me da un error, la ruta dinamica seria: http://localhost:3000/data.json/view/francia

Lo unico que estoy buscando es encontrar una forma en la que al hacer click a cualquier bandera esta me renderize informacion en funcion de params.name que yo capture. reemplazando el JSON.stringify() por propiedades del api, pero  no puedo hacerlo, la funcion no devuelve nada, pero nose como solucionar o encarar este problema, ayuda por favor.
